# What's up with EasyClangComplete on Sublime?

Tags: c++, c++11, sublimetext3, std, sfml

I recently started using Sublime, with SFML built from source. I migrated my Core::Blocks project to Sublime (put source and header files in good folders and made a Sublime project that uses them). Everything is compiling nicely and it works well, with some minor issues.

There is one problem, though; EasyClangComplete doesn't recognize `std`. When I write `std::string` with `#include <string>`, `std` is in a red rectangle and the alert says "unrecognizable identifier". What's weirder, the syntax highlighting of Sublime itself doesn't recognize `std`, because `std::` is white, and `sf::` from SFML or `ios::` are green. What have I missed?

Comment: I'm using Windows, Clang 6.0.0 and gcc 6.3.0(mingw-w64). I also didn't manage to make it recognize the `std::` namespace. Since I'm not using CMake, I tried 3 of the recommended methods for adding include flags in the docs(`"common_flags"` in User Setting, .clang_complete file in the root of my project folder, `"common_flags"` in the sublime project file). Tried adding every include dir and subdir of both compilers, but no results. It works just fine for parsing / autocomplete-ing symbols from my own project headers. Glancing over the issues in the repo it seems there's no Windows support.

Comment: @Running_Sloth: Are you on Windows? Do you have Microsoft Build Tools installed? Clang should find std headers automatically in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow missed this question, sorry. Since you asked this question, I have added the docs to the plugin and there should be an easier way to configure it on Windows with MinGW. See the settings example here: https://niosus.github.io/EasyClangComplete/settings/#common_flags

For completeness, your `common_flags` should look smth like:

```
"common_flags" : [
    "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++",
    "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++\\mingw32"
],
```